# How to use window function and Group by in same Query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to user window function and group by clause in same query

```
SELECT customer,flag ,
FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY customer ,flag
order by (case when price > 0 then DATEDIFF(date(create_date), date('2000-01-01')) end) DESC)
 AS `Last Price`
FROM
  (SELECT customer,create_date,flag,price FROM customer) AS virtual_table
WHERE create_date >= '2015-01-01'
  AND create_date < '2023-02-17'
GROUP BY customer,flag
```

The query is working fine without group by clause(which I already know how to do it). Why can't we use group by here? Please tell what causing the Query to be incorrect?

Comment: window functions are applied *after* grouping.  if you need to group after window functions, you need to use a subquery and group in an outer query.  please do explain what you are trying to do, as your select does not make that at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't we use group by here?

You try to use non-grouped `price` and `create_date` in window function which is incorrect.

Window function is applied after GROUP BY. So the columns visibility in your query is equal to

```
SELECT customer,flag ,

/* FIRST_VALUE( */ 
    price,
/* ) OVER (PARTITION BY */ 
    customer,
    flag,
/* order by (case when */ 
    price,
/* > 0 then DATEDIFF(date( */
    create_date
/* ), date('2000-01-01')) end) DESC) */
/* AS `Last Price` */

FROM
  (SELECT customer,create_date,flag,price FROM customer) AS virtual_table
WHERE create_date >= '2015-01-01'
  AND create_date < '2023-02-17'
GROUP BY customer,flag
```

Now you can see that the query is not correct.